# C#でポインタのアドレスが返ってくるDLLの呼び出し方法

Tags: c#

こんにちは、お世話になります。

C#でCで作成されたDLLを呼び出そうとしています。  
そこで1つ困ったことがあるので、質問させてください。

今回利用しようとしているDLLは、下記からダウンロードできる「Tags」というものです。

http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?z/3/tags18

そして、このDLLでは、戻り値にポインタの先頭位置のアドレスが返ってくるようなんですが、このような関数の呼び出し方がわからずにいます。  
ちなみに、Cの関数宣言では、下記のようになっています。

```
const char* _stdcall TAGS_Read(
    DWORD handle,
    const char* fmt
);
```

また、リファレンスによると、戻り値は下記のように記述されています。

```
- empty string when unable to properly read the tag, or when there are no supported tags.
- pointer to the beginning of a text string, containing extracted
  values from the song tags, on success;
- a parser error message text, when format string is ill-formed.
```

説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、このような関数の呼び出し方および返ってきたアドレスを基にデータを取得する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: たとえポインタを得ても C# (manage) 側から C++ (unmanage) 側のメモリを直接アクセスすることはできません。マーシャラに任せるのが一番簡単なのですが、そのためには C++ 側が返却するポインタが指すメモリの素性がわからないと dllimport が書けません。というわけで、その `Read` が返すポインタについてもっと説明してください。

Comment: すみません。かなり情報が不足していたため、質問文を編集しました。そちらをごらんいただければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

774RRさんが

> たとえポインタを得ても C# (manage) 側から C++ (unmanage) 側のメモリを直接アクセスすることはできません。

と否定されていますが実はできます。当該コードはダウンロードしておらずその意味では「そのためには C++ 側が返却するポインタが指すメモリの素性がわからないと」という前置きが付きますが、例えば

```
[DllImport("filename.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr TAGS_Read(int handle, string fmt);
```

と定義でき、[`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/7b620dhe(v=vs.110).aspx)を使用して`'\0'`までの文字列を`string`として読み出したり、[`Marshal.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms146631(v=vs.110).aspx)を使用してバイト配列に読み込んだりできます。

ただし、774RRさんが言われるように「メモリの素性」によっては「マーシャラに任せるのが一番簡単」です。（確保されたメモリを誰がどのように解放するか次第）

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。「Marshal.Copy」を利用しようと思ったんですが、ポインタの長さがわからないんですよね。

Comment: あれからいろいろ試してみました。「Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi」や「Marshal.PtrToStringUni」で

Comment: あれからいろいろ試してみました。「Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi」や「Marshal.PtrToStringUni」を使えば、一応文字列は読み取れるんですが、Unicodeの文字（絵文字とか）が文字化けしてしまうようです。一番いいのは、バイト型配列で取得できればいいのですが、うまい方法がわからずにいます。そもそもDLLの関数宣言で戻り値に「string」を指定すれば、文字列は取れるっぽいんですが、「byte[]」を指定すると、エラーが発生してしまうようです。何かアドバイス等があれば、お願いします。

Comment: @user29034 「C#から正しい文字列を読み出せない」ことが原因なのか、「C言語レベルでそもそも間違った文字列しか返していない」ことが原因なのか、切り分けできていますか？ 後者が原因であれば本質問の範囲外で、Tagsの使い方の質問になるわけですが。

Comment: 下記サイトを参考にしたら、うまくいきました。
https://qiita.com/grayhead0603/items/c2259610e2139b948e2b
ありがとうございました。